URL Bar Showing in TWA Even After Uploading Fingerprint
I'm working on a Trusted Web Activity (TWA) app, and I encountered an issue.
After I uploaded the assetlinks.json file containing the correct SHA-256 fingerprint on my website, the URL bar still appears when the TWA is launched.
Despite these steps, the TWA still shows the URL bar, which shouldn't happen once the fingerprint is verified.
Has anyone faced a similar issue, or could there be something I'm missing? Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
App link details
URL bar showing
Statement List Generator and Tester
`Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Uploaded the assetlinks.json file to https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
Made sure the fingerprint matches the one from my Android app signing key.
Checked the URL to ensure that the file is accessible and correctly formatted.`

